# Digital Signature Using USB Token. How to pass a password automatically with the iTextSharp MakeSignature.SignDetached method?

Tags: c#, itext

MakeSignature.SignDetached is the function I am using in iTextSharp. How do I pass the Password automatically without completing a popup entry?
Here is my code.

```
        X509Store st = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        st.Open(OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = st.Certificates;
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
        {
            foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
            {
                certClient = cert;
                string username = certClient.Subject;
                string startdate = certClient.GetEffectiveDateString();
                string enddate = certClient.GetExpirationDateString();
           
                if (collection[i].Subject.Contains("EXAMPLE"))
                {
                    certClient = collection[i];
                }
            }
        }


        IList<X509Certificate> chain = new List<X509Certificate>();
        X509Chain x509Chain = new X509Chain();
        x509Chain.Build(certClient);
       
        foreach (X509ChainElement x509ChainElement in x509Chain.ChainElements)
        {
            chain.Add(DotNetUtilities.FromX509Certificate(x509ChainElement.Certificate));
        }
        IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(certClient, "SHA-256");
        PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.SignatureAppearance;
        signatureAppearance.Reason = "For Invoice";
        signatureAppearance.Acro6Layers = false;
        signatureAppearance.Layer4Text = PdfSignatureAppearance.questionMark;
        signatureAppearance.SignDate = DateTime.Now;
        signatureAppearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(100, 50, 300, 100), inputPdf.NumberOfPages, "KARTHIK");
        signatureAppearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;
        MakeSignature.SignDetached(signatureAppearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

[Example Password PopUp Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj0W0.png)

While **MakeSignature** it's asking for a password in popup screen. But I'd like to pass a Password by coding wise. Is this possible and How?

Answer (score 0):

Well I use itext for java, but I see that you are using X509Certificate2Signature to apply signature. Instead you can create a custom class from IExternalSignature interface and specify how to obtain the private key to sign.

Something like this: https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/digital-signatures-chapter-4